# React: Radio Buttons/Checkboxes on iOS not checking correctly

Tags: reactjs, safari, jsx

In my react project, I have a checkbox which works fine in all desktop browsers but seems to fail on iOS Safari (and possibly Android). It takes about 5 to 10 clicks for a checkbox to get checked:

```
_onChange = (index, e) => {
    const {checked} = e.target;

    this.setState({
        checked
    });
};

render() {
        <input className="checkbox"
               type="checkbox"
               checked={ this.state.checked }
               onChange={ this._onChange.bind(this, index) }
        />
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns this is a [`fastclick`](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) issue: The regular `fastclick` doesn't seem to address the issue, but `react-fastclick` seems to have fixed it:

https://github.com/JakeSidSmith/react-fastclick/issues/22

So the solution was simply to use `react-fastclick` instead.